# Get Call SID-Recording could be done successfull

Tags: c#, twilio

How to get the Call SID  and recording SID of that call once the call recording is done from Twilio 'Dial' method.

```
var dial = new Dial(callerId: callerId, record: record_from_answer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't get the call SID and recording SID directly from the `Dial` method. However, you can set up to receive a webhook when the recording is complete.

For this you need to set the [`recordingStatusCallback` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#attributes-recording-status-callback) to a absolute or relative URL in your application.

```
var dial = new Dial(
  callerId: callerId,
  record: record_from_answer,
  recordingStatusCallback: new Uri("https://www.myexample.com/recording")
);
```

Then, when the recording is ready your application will receive a webhook to that URL with the parameters `CallSid` and `RecordingSid` in the request body.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: how we can achieve this functionality using native iOS and android apps ?

Comment: If you want the recording information, you need to be running a server I'm afraid. When the recording is complete Twilio makes a webhook to your URL. There are other things you can do natively, like make calls from your app using the [Twilio Programmable Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk) but you will eventually need a server for that too.

Comment: I understand , Thanks for your help